# Searching a pattern in linux

Tags: shell, sed, grep

I have a file containing:

```
abc=1234.121
```

How to get only the numerical part?

```
1234.121
```

Comment: This has been answered soooo many times. Anyone willing to find a good duplicate instead of posting an answer?

Comment: OMG, i can't find any..

Comment: lol Avinash :D, but @user3796546 before posting any question please check if similar question exists or google,yahoo etc. provides you the answer or hint.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`

```
sed 's/.*=//g'
```

Comment: You are most welcome. You can accept it so that I will get a green tick.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`cut`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29),

```
echo abc=1234.121 | cut -f2 -d'='|cut -f1 -d'.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some `awk` version:

```
echo "abc=1234.121" | awk -F= '$0=$2'
1234.121
```

```
echo "abc=1234.121" | awk -F= '{print $2}'
1234.121
```